# Sorting numerical arguments to command while keeping index

Tags: macros

I am currently struggling with a somewhat complex command idea (at least for my level of skill) and would like some criticism, tips and comments from the community.

I have a new command `lstin` taking 4 numerical arguments, which currently processes the values and only outputs non-zero values together with a text identifier and places a comma between the individual blocks if required.

The current structure looks like

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newboolean{commaid}
\setboolean{commaid}{false}

\newcommand\lstin[4]{
\IfStrEq{#1}{0}{}{A~(#1)\setboolean{commaid}{true}}%
\IfStrEq{#2}{0}{}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{commaid}}{, }{}B~(#2)\setboolean{commaid}{true}}%
\IfStrEq{#3}{0}{}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{commaid}}{, }{}C~(#3)\setboolean{commaid}{true}}%
\IfStrEq{#4}{0}{}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{commaid}}{, }{}D~(#4)}%
}
```

For example, `\lstin{0}{8}{12}{0}` returns `B (8), C (12)`. However, my wish would be to sort this output by size. Say in just mentioned example the output should be `C (12), B (8)`.

My normal programming approach would be to use an array that is sorted and then use old and new position in the array accordingly for output. However, my current level of knowledge, also in combination with a somewhat longer research, do not let me see a solution at the moment.

Therefore I would be maximally grateful for any kind of comments, help or improvement especially also to my general approach.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with `expl3`.

I populate a sequence with items of the form

```
\__lpo_lstin_item:nn {<value>}{<letter}
```

that I can sort based on the `<value>` (the sorting code exploits `\use_ii:nnn` that returns the second part, so `<value>`). The item is added only if nonzero.

At the end, the sequence is delivered with “comma and space” between items; the command `\__lpo_lstin_item:nn` prints the letter in parentheses, a nonbreaking space and the value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the user interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\lstin}{mmmm}
 {
  \lpo_lstin:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

% variables
\seq_new:N \l_lpo_lstin_items_seq

% the internal function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \lpo_lstin:nnnn
 {
  % populate the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_lpo_lstin_items_seq
  \__lpo_lstin_add:nn { #1 } { A }
  \__lpo_lstin_add:nn { #2 } { B }
  \__lpo_lstin_add:nn { #3 } { C }
  \__lpo_lstin_add:nn { #4 } { D }
  % sort the sequence
  \__lpo_lstin_sort:
  % deliver the result
  \seq_use:Nn \l_lpo_lstin_items_seq { ,~ }
 }

% auxiliary functions

% add the item only if nonzero
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lpo_lstin_add:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 == 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_lpo_lstin_items_seq { \__lpo_lstin_item:nn {#1}{#2} }
   }
 }
% sort the sequence
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lpo_lstin_sort:
 {
  \seq_sort:Nn \l_lpo_lstin_items_seq
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \use_ii:nnn ##1 } > { \use_ii:nnn ##2 }
     {
      \sort_return_same:
     }
     {
      \sort_return_swapped:
     }
   }
 }
% print the item
\cs_new:Nn \__lpo_lstin_item:nn { (#2)\nobreakspace #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lstin{4}{3}{2}{1}

\lstin{1}{2}{3}{4}

\lstin{0}{8}{12}{0}

\end{document}
```

[image]